# I need to convert the Arraylist of hashmap to DTO below in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, hashmap

I want to covert the `Linkedhashmap` to the below DTO object

```
INPUT HASHMAP:[{
          param1 = Hello,
          Year 1 Value = 600,
          Year 2 Value = 600,
        },
        {
          param2 = Hello,
          Year 1 Result = 500,
          Year 2 Result = 700,
        }]
        
        Desire Output DTO
              
            private String paramname;
        //paramname will have param1.param2 names;
            private List<ResultDto> data;
        
            List<ResultDto>
            private Long year; 
            private long value;
    //year 1 will have value respectively
```

please check the loops which will work here or any better performance iterations .
I tried the many approach through for loop.

Comment: Show your map declaration and code for DTO class.